# HTML table-cell how to set width

Tags: html, css

How can I force width to elements with display: table-cell?

```
<div id="wraper">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>Right and Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS doesn't do anything, width of #left and #righ elements isnt affected.

```
#wraper {
  display: table-wrap;
}
#left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
#right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  width 70%;
}
```

Comment: 30% of what? The table has to have a width first.

Comment: Although there is no such CSS property as "table-wrap", your code works just fine for me. The widths are 30/70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just works fine for me 
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qq0t46pt/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wraper">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>Right and Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wraper {
  display: table-wrap;
}
#left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
#right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  width 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`table-wrap` is not a valid `display` value. See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Use `display:table`.

Then you need to give the table a width so the child elements can calculate their own width accordingly.

```css
#wraper {
  display: table;
  width: 70%; /* or your chosen value */
  margin: auto;
}
#left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
#right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  width 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wraper">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>Right and Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```